# How to use OpenCV with C# (Commercial use)

Tags: c#, opencv

I am trying to do a project in C#. For now, I want to just stream and save video from 2 PC cameras at the same time, but will be using more of OpenCV later on.

I came EmguCV, but they have separate terms for commercial license: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Licensing:

Is there some other good alternative I can use to get OpenCV working with C#? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [OpenCvSharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp)? It is licensed under the [BSD 3-Clause License](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/blob/master/LICENSE), so commercial use should be no problem.

Some colleagues of mine use OpenCvSharp in their projects, and I haven't heard any bad from them about it.